# Python extracting excel cells

Tags: python, excel

I'm reading hundreds of excel files and searching for a string then the value next to that string. The problem I'm facing is that the string is rarely in the same cell. As an example:

Sheet 1

```
        Name             Amount
        foo              15
        bar              23
        bin              10
```

Sheet 2

```
        Name             Amount
        bin              28
        foo              10
        bar              6
```

I would like to read the files, and write | foo | # | in another excel sheet with each instance being a new line.

I'm struggling with an approach to take.

Desired output

```
       Name            Amount
       foo             15
       foo             10
```

Comment: Please add an example of the desired output

Comment: Why not use pandas `DataFrame` to read, process and ouput the final excel ?

Comment: @FabienP there's probably a 100 ways to do this that I'm unaware of. Trying to explore all options and find what's best. Is DataFrame easy/efficient to use? I come from an R background with basic python understanding/skills.

Comment: @ASavage: Can you provide more info about how your excel tables are arranged? Are they all sheets from a same file? Do they have all the same format? (location, columns names, number of columns, ...)

Comment: @FabienP sure! The sheets are coming from different files, however all have the same naming scheme "xyz-001" or "xyz-002" for file names and each sheet within the file is named "sheetname". They all have a similar format, just with different orders based on line items that are added or removed. The data _starts_ at cell C14 on each sheet and it's consistent.

Comment: A sample sheet, unchanged, as csv would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter
#use zero based columns
name_col=0
value_col=1
#make a big dict with all the name value pairs ... this might come in handy later
foo=dict([itemgetter(name_col,val_col)(sheet.get_row_values(i))for i in range(nRows)]).get('foo',None)

print "FOO:",foo
```

something like that i think would work ... if you dont really care about the dict of all values you could probably just do something like

```
def get_foo(sheet,nRows):
   for i in range(nRows):
       values = sheet.get_row_values()
       if 'foo' in values:
          return values[values.index('foo')+1]
```

where you bail out once you find your value